# Compare results of two queries laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables like below:

**cat**

```
+-------------------------------+
|   id | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  |
+-------------------------------+
| name | Hi | Ho | Hu | Ha | He |
+-------------------------------+
```

**selected cat**

```
+----------------+
|   id | 2 | 5   |
+----------------+
| name | Ho | He |
+----------------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1 - > No
2 - > Yes
3 - > No
4 - > No
5 - > Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id,
case when id in (select distinct id from selected_cat) then 'Yes'
else 'No' end
as somecol
from cat;
```

You can use a `case` statement to check for the existence of id in the other table.

Comment: Works good, Thank you bro!